# Oracle error due to non ascii characters in xmlelement method

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I’m getting xml parsing failed error on this select query. ‘Colname’ contains non-ascii values. How to make this query not to fail due to the non-ascii characters.

```
SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,colname,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY colname).GetClobVal(),',')
FROM tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use replace for special characters. Like: replace(column_name,'<','&lt'). The replace should be applied for each special character.
For a list of special chars, see: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/EAI5/EAI5_Overview5.html